# How to get the EntryID of a mailitem that is encrypted

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, office-addins, mapi

In a VSTO Outlook C# addin I want to loop through a folder of items that are all encrypted mailitems and get the EntryID or MAPIOBJECT as I plan to send it on to extended MAPI.

```
foreach (object olObject in folder.Items)
{
    if (olObject is Outlook.MailItem olM)
    {
        //olM.EntryID fails
    }
}
```

Where mailitems are encrypted with PKI and the private key is stored on a personal card inserted into the PC, the user must have at least opened 1 encrypted mailitem for the OOM to be able to read properties of a mailitem. At the time of looking at the folder items I do not know if this is the case or not.

I have found that if I cast an `Outlook.Selection` to a mailitem I can then get the entryID. Would there be some way of doing the same with folder.Items?

I also note that mailItem.MAPIOBJECT will also throw an exception if no encrypted items have been viewed by the user.

The problem with hitting this error is not catching it, it is that Outlook takes too long to throw an exception. Is there any way to quickly workout that Outlook cannot read the encrypted items yet?

The only option I see at the moment is to wait for an inspector window to open on a mailitem that was encrypted. The problem with this is that if the user takes their card out then no encrypted mail items can be read.

**UPDATE** With respect to knowing if Outlook can read encrypted emails or not Dmitry below in the comments has confirmed you cannot, my current strategy is to listen for an inspector window to open with a mailitem that is encrypted. If this is open it means that the user has entered their pin for the card in their reader and supplied Outlook with access to their private key to decrypt that mailitem. From this point all mailitem properties like EntryID or MAPIOBJECT do not error for all mailitems, until either Outlook is closed or the card is pulled from the reader. In this case I am using Net.Pkcs11Interop to detect card readers, cards, certificates events. I am also going to check out the [Windows.Devices.SmartCards Namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.smartcards?view=winrt-22621) in UWP world as this might be a little easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not just loop through all items in a loop - use [MAPIFolder.GetTable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.folder.gettable) to retrieve multiple properties from multiple items in a single call. Besides being able to retrieve the entry ids of encrypted messages, the call will also be be much faster.

Comment: Yes that gives you access to the EntryIDs perfect. Any hints on how to know if Outlook can decrypt yet or not?

Comment: You won't know if Outlook can decrypt it until you actually try, but you can filter out encrypted messages by retrieving the `MessageClass` property as well and skipping items with the message class starting with `IPM.NOTE.SMIME' (can be `IPM.NOTE.SMIME` or `IPM.NOTE.SMIME.MultipartSigned`).

Comment: That is what I originally suggested doing.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check out the `MessageClass` property first. Encrypted emails have `IPM.Note.SMIME` value set.

However, remember that third-party add-ins may encrypt messages without changing the message class or security flags. They will look like a regular email. In that case, you will have to parse the message body to detect them.

Also you may check the PR_SECURITY_FLAGS property value.

```
    Const PR_SECURITY_FLAGS = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x6E010003"
    Const SECFLAG_ENCRYPTED As Long = &H1    

    Dim SecFlags As Long

    ' Get current flags value
    SecFlags = oItem.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty(PR_SECURITY_FLAGS)
```

Comment: trying to access the PropertyAccessor where the user has not decrypted one mailitem also (eventually) throws an exception. This is exactly what I am trying to avoid.

Comment: Does the message class property throw an exception?

Comment: It is not about an email it is about Outlook. From Dmitry's comment he believes you cannot. I will update my question as to my strategy on this.

Comment: You came back to my suggestion to use the `MessageClass` property.

Comment: Not really. I wanted to clear up what I am asking. I am sorry for asking it incorrectly. The message class of a mailitem is important but what I want to know is when the OOM can actually do something with an IPM.NOTE.SMIME and the MAPIOBJECT. if the user has not opened a IPM.NOTE.SMIME mailitem then MAPIOBJECT will throw an exception and it takes Outlook too long to throw it (in my opinion) sometimes not responding as well for a few seconds.

Comment: I understood your point initially.